# for-loop in loop syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, for-loop, syntax-error

I'm trying to run a program called aldy on several .json files with a list of items (A, B, C, D)

I want to use the file name without the extension
like bob in bob.json, amy in amy.json

The desired output would be 
bob.a.txt, bob.b.txt, ...
amy.a.txt, amy.b.txt, ...

The code I have

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

LIST=('A' 'B' 'C' 'D')

for file in *.json; do
     filename=${file%%.*}       
    for i in "${LIST}"; do
        outfile = $filename + ".${i}.txt"
        aldy -g ${i} -o $outfile $file
    done
done
```

However, I got error message and I don't really know how to fix this.

syntax error: unexpected end of file

Any help would be greatly appreciated 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Copy and paste your script to https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following corrections:

- `for i in "${LIST[@]}"; do`. That's how you get all elements of an array.
- `outfile=${filename}.${i}.txt`.

  1. There may be no spaces around `=` in assignments.
  2. Concatenating variables is done by placing them next to one another. You can use braces (as in `${expandthis}butnotthis`) to delimit them, but in your case simply `$filename.$i.txt` would do (`.` serves as delimiter).
- `aldy -g "$i" -o "$outfile" "$file"`. Quote your variables when expanding them. If you always do it, either the quotes will be redundant, or (in most cases) they will prevent problems caused by word splitting and globbing.

Comment: Thank you so much!! All the explanation makes it very clear :)